# Request works from Postman but not from cURL

Tags: curl, postman

I have a pretty simple Postman request that works just fine in Postman. It's just a GET request to the following URL:

```
http://www.toysrus.com/storefrontsearch/stores.jsp?skuId=24654884&quantity=1&postalCode=48103&latitude&longitude&productId=107531766&startIndexForPagination=0&searchRadius=0&pageType=product&ispu_or_sts=null&displayAllStoresFlag=false&displayAllStoreLink=false
```

If I ask Postman to make a cURL request out of that for me, it gives me this:

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://www.toysrus.com/storefrontsearch/stores.jsp?skuId=24654884&quantity=1&postalCode=48103&latitude=&longitude=&productId=107531766&startIndexForPagination=0&searchRadius=0&pageType=product&ispu_or_sts=null&displayAllStoresFlag=false&displayAllStoreLink=false' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'postman-token: b4ae79c0-c3f0-8247-8c2f-306c43376039'
```

The result is that it just hangs forever and never gives me a response.

Any idea what can be done to get the cURL request working?

Comment: Update: I discovered that a GET request will work just fine in Postman, which I believe slightly simplifies the problem.

Comment: Then remove the `-X GET` from the curl line...

Comment: Like I said, my `curl` command is just coming straight out of Postman. I infer that the command will be functionally equivalent whether `-X GET` is present or absent and so removing it wouldn't change anything. (I tried the command without the `-X GET` just to make sure I'm not crazy and the request seemed to fail in the same way.)

Comment: your url doesn't work. it redirects to 404 page

Comment: The URL does work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems the server has banned curl user-agent, also the cookies `troute=t1` needs to be set otherwise it returns 404 :

```
curl -L -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla' \
        -H 'Cookie: troute=t1;' \
        'http://www.toysrus.com/storefrontsearch/stores.jsp?skuId=24654884&quantity=1&postalCode=48103&latitude&longitude&productId=107531766&startIndexForPagination=0&searchRadius=0&pageType=product&ispu_or_sts=null&displayAllStoresFlag=false&displayAllStoreLink=false' --compressed
```

Answer (score 4):

**Beware of the cookie monster**

Not all Postman requests are made equal.

Postman will store cookies [whether you like it or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49511266/1328) (and send them over in subsequent calls to the same domain).

I didn't realize my first call to the same domain was receiving a cookie that was sent back on the next call from Postman. So even though everything looked the same, I wasn't sending the cookie through curl.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a GET request, without a body, from within Postman, remember to specify the body parameter as "none" so that a --Data [] parameter is not generated for the cURL code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jj7S.png)