# How to disable cookies in Postman Application

Tags: cookies, postman

I'm using Postman application to test APIs in Ubuntu 16.04.

I don't need Postman to store cookies after API request. I only find options to delete cookies manually for each request. Does anyone know how to completely disable it?

Comment: You can remove cookies in a pre-script. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60114110/1121497

Comment: Also notice that you need to whitelist the domain to access cookies: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/cookies/#whitelisting-domains-for-programmatic-access-of-cookies

Comment: I have left a feature request on their forums [here](https://community.postman.com/t/feature-request-allow-disabling-redirects-and-cookies-globally/28296) for disabling cookies globally. If you need different settings to the defaults, consider making a "template" request that has the settings you need and duplicating it each time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is still an open issue on the project and the only way that i’ve been able to do, is delete them through the UI.

Answer (score 33):

Go to "settings" tab and disable "cookie jar" and "follow redirects".

Thus, Postman will act as fetch in node-js for instance. It will acts as it is the first attempt to login (or whatever) and you'll see a fresh response every time.

Comment: To be more clear: this is about the "Settings" tab of a request, not the general "Postman Settings" Section. And YES, it needs to be done for each request.

Answer (score 4):

[Check out the settings section within the project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9weNc.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32364105)

Comment: Instead of linking to an image, describe what the image says in the text of your answer.  Embed the image directly if you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use version 6.1.3, which had a bug in it which prevented to send cookies on subsequent request. See https://community.getpostman.com/t/postman-no-longer-send-cookie-with-subsequent-requests/1723

But it's hard to get your hand on that version, it is not on https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/release-notes because they only show major versions 7.

Comment: OMG, don't go this path... :)