# Retrieve response from API with Zeppelin (Spark Interpreter) using Scala

Tags: scala, data-science, apache-zeppelin

I am a beginner to data science and starting my learning journey using Apache Zeppelin and Spark.

My idea was to play with the English Premier League's Fantasy league api (url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/') and do some analysis/data manipulation on the data retrieved from the API.

I have been trying to make a GET request to this endpoint (using Scala) in a new zeppelin note but however I cannot, I tried to use this [`script`](https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/scala/scala-get-content-rest-url-get-rest-content/) but nothing was returned.

I would appreciate any help on how to get data back from this endpoint using Scala and/or my approach to the problem. Thank You.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Request works from Postman but not from cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889150/request-works-from-postman-but-not-from-curl)

Comment: Set the header as in the document.

Comment: I tried that and sadly it didn't work, I think [this](https://documentation.mindsphere.io/resources/html/predictive-learning/en-US/Making_API_Calls_from_Zeppelin_Notebook.htm) might be what I'm trying to achieve but its in python

Comment: I basically want to make an api call to that URL and work with the response in Apache Zeppelin using Scala.